# Перенос Личных сайтов пользователей SharePoint 2013 на новый сервер SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

Приветствую. Подключил БД контента личных сайтов пользователя к новому серверу. Перед этим предварительно настроена была служба профилей и включены "Личные сайты".

Но после подключения БД контента личных сайтов, юзер (у которого раньше уже была своя страничка на 2013-ом сервере) ткнувшись по ссылке "сайты" попадает на диалог нового создания сайта. Как будто бы у него его раньше не было.

Причем, если для этого веб-приложения смотрю коллекцию сайтов - она заполнена юзерами. т.е. как будто бы сайты юзерские есть но они никому не видны ((

Подскажите куда рыть???

Comment: Может после переноса, сайты перенеслись, а владельцы (регистрация) нет? Т.е. пользователь видит "свой" сайт, но не видит что он его владеец.

Comment: Его сайт видит админ из админской консоли, в списке сайтов. Но реально никто туда зайти не может. (

Comment: У вас пользователи+роли+групы созданы и назначены? Может stsadmin security вам поможет? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287951%28v=office.12%29.aspx Посмотреть их enumusers enumroles enumgroups

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы после переноса нормально работал **OneDrive** и **личные сайты** — надо обязательно апгрейдить User Profiles Service и скорее всего Managed Metadata Service (часть данных в нем тоже может храниться). *Причём сначала апгрейдить службы и только потом БД контента*. Потом надо [обновить](http://ulmaskulov.blogspot.ru/2017/08/SP2016SocialSubscrUrl.html) подписки на сайты.